# Convert specific symbols to normal utf-8 from json

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, json, nsstring

I get json string from server. Then I parser it using SBJSON library. But when I show parse results in my label I have symbols like that

```
&#33;
```

(normally it's !).

So how can I convert my json string to normal string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this: https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/NSString+HTML.m (specifically, the `stringByDecodingHTMLEntities` method).

Comment: Turn in a [bug report](https://bugreport.apple.com/) to Apple requesting support for Decoding HTML Entities, the more the better chance Apple will add it to the SDKs.